# If an interior wall is right below a joist or beam, do I still need the upper plate?

Tags: drywall, framing

Like the title says, if the wall is right underneath a joist or beam, I think I can just attach the studs to them instead of adding a plate? Or do I still need a plate? If so, why?

(Thanks a lot for the responses. Just to clarify, in this case the wall is not load bearing.)

Comment: When you say "right underneath", do you mean that the new wall will be running parallel to a joist above, but will _not_ be load bearing (i.e., you're installing a new divider wall in an existing space, not doing new construction where this wall is supporting the beam above)?

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for bringing it up. The wall is not load bearing and I've clarified.

Answer (score 1):

If the wall is load bearing, then yes you must (assuming you must follow [international building code](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IBC2018P6/chapter-23-wood/IBC2018P6-Ch23-Sec2308.5.3.2)). This would be to properly distribute the load from above down to the stud ends.

Regardless, it is easier to attach a wall through a top plate  after having made the studs straight on the ground than with a bunch of toe nails on each stud while on a ladder. Also, it gives you a nailing surface for attaching drywall.

Comment: Additionally, if you can build the wall flat on the floor then stand it up, it is _much_ easier to get the studs straight, parallel and in the same plane than trying to nail each one up once they're all vertical. And, once the wall is standing, properly aligned and vertical, it's dead simple to nail straight up through the top plate and into the joist above to hold it in place.

Comment: This isn't true. You could absolutely build a wall under a beam with no plate. For one thing, the studs would essentially be trimmers if the wall is bearing load, and they don't require a plate. For another, if they're under a beam it's not load-bearing anyway. Finally, we can assume that the OP has a _reason_ for not wanting to use a plate, so your final paragraph is moot.

Comment: @FreeMan, walls built between concrete slabs and beams rarely have a consistent height. Studs often need to be custom fit individually. This is easier when _not_ prebuilt as an assembly. We don't whether we're on concrete, but it's a safe bet.

Comment: Thanks! If I build the wall on the ground, is it easy for the wall to be too tall/short?  That's the main reason I was planning to attach the studs vertically to the plates.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't. From what you describe we can surmise one of two likely situations, neither of which require a plate.

- The wall isn't load-bearing. Therefore, build it as you like to suit your needs. I've installed studs directly under beams many times.
- The studs *are* bearing the beam. In this case no plate between is warranted (or commonly installed), as these are simply trimmer studs.

Comment: Downvoters, please speak up. I'm quite confident in this answer but always willing to learn.